# Variable is empty when passed to bash

Tags: linux, bash, aws-cli, sudo, assume-role

I have a bash script that assumes an IAM role and then pass the credentials to the next command:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su <<EOF

aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/SomeRole" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session > /awsCredential

awscurl https://someApi --request POST --region us-west-2 --access_key $(cat /awsCredential | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')

EOF
```

When running the script, `$(cat /awsCredential | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')` resolved to empty, but if I run the above commands manually from terminal, I can see it resolves to the AWS ACCESS KEY ID returned from the assume role command, does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Which variable would that be? I don't see any variables in your script.

Comment: The `cat` command is being executed by the original user, not the root. Do you have read permission to the file?

Comment: Use `<<'EOF'` so that the command substitution will not be executed when the here-doc is expanded, it will be executed by the superuser shell.